# I would like to buy DSO138 oscilloscope to measure DC converters output voltage. What is the max frequency?

Tags: oscilloscope

The DSO138 scope: [enter link description here](http://www.jyetech.com/Products/LcdScope/e138.php)

in the description there is: 'Analog bandwidth: 0 - 200KHz'

What does it mean?

If I would like to measure DC converters output voltage and the DC converter operates at 500kHz or 1mHz than I can't able to measure the output ripple?

Comment: That scope is only barely good enough for audio circuits.. you need a scope that is much higher frequency than the number you want to measure.

Answer (score 1):

Oscilloscope bandwidth tells you how high of a sine wave you can see before it's attenuated more than 3 dB. You can check out this quick video I put together a while back:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VBJWkceO1OA

Answer (score 0):

scope bandwidth means the maximum frequency that the scope can measure without introducing errors , so this scope can work well up to 200 khz , and as you want to measure higher frequencies you should buy a scope with bandwidth  higher than the frequencies of your interest